# Telegram API CallBack + IIS

Tags: c#, iis

**UPD2**
Установив на сервер tshark, поймал ошибку такую

> 38 282.396282475  91.108.6.58 → 192.168.1.98 TLSv1.2 992 [TCP Previous
> segment not captured] , Ignored Unknown Record
> При CallBack от ТГ.

**Конец UPD2**

**UPD:**
Поднял ubuntu server, настроил nginx, получил сертификаты letsencrypt. Запустил приложение.
Бот заработал, но опять CALLBACK не доходит до приложения.
Делаю вывод, что проблема была не в IIS.
Куда копать не понимаю.
**конец upd**

Не могу развернуть бота на IIS.

Что имею:

.net core 3.1,

win server 2019 + iis

Написал код, для отладки использовал ngrok Tunell. Все устроило все работало в режиме отладки.
Начал разворачивать на IIS. Установил SSL сертификат, настроил А запись. Бот запустился, заработал. На сообщения отвечает, до момента пока не начинается магия в виде CallBack вызовов, которые нужны для пролистывания галереи картинок.

Думал где то падает, добавил везде try/catch, где только можно. Не помогло. Решил сделать в лоб, просто ловить входящее сообщение и записывать его в файл.

```
[Route("api/message/update")]
    public class MessageController : Controller
    {        
        public Client client { get; set; }           
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {

            return "123";
        }  

        [HttpPost]
        
     
         public async Task<OkResult> Post([FromBody]Update update)
        {
            try
            {               
                var botClient = await Bot.GetBotClientAsync();
                Bot.MyLogger(("InputMessage " + update.Id); 
                if (update.CallbackQuery != null)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        var callbackQuery = update.CallbackQuery;

                        Bot.MyLogger("ExecuteCallbackMessage " + callbackQuery.Data);

                        await ExecuteCallbackMessage(callbackQuery, botClient);
                      
                        return Ok();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Bot.MyLogger(ex.Message);
                        var t = ex;
                        return Ok();
                    }

                }
                else if (update == null) return Ok();

                var message = update.Message;
                client = new Client();
                client.ChatId = (int)message.Chat.Id;
                await ExecuteCommand(message, botClient);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Bot.MyLogger(ex.Message);
                return Ok();
            }
        }
```

При обычной отправке сообщения из ТГ на строчке

```
Bot.MyLogger(("InputMessage " + update.Id);
```

происходит запись в файл следующего вида:

> 16.11.2020 20:13:21 InputMessage 417633691

Если делается CallBack вызов кнопки, то такое ощущение, что запрос не доходит вообще, потому что записи не делается никакой.
Все бы хорошо, но в режиме отладки через ngrok - все работает как часы.
Смотрел через WireShark - пакеты летят.
Есть подозрение, что гонит сам IIS. Но почему - непонятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем спустя недели мучений я исправил это.

Дело было в значении MTU на роутере, которое было выставлено в размере 1500. Сменив значение на 1492 пакеты полетели нормально. Кто бы мог подумать...

Зато я поднял навыки в настройке nginx, повспоминал команды в терминале ubuntu. Научился стартовать приложения в линуксе, подымать их в качестве сервиса)))

**upd**

Стоит роутер zyxel keenetic II. После смены мту перестали открываться страницы в браузере. Проблема была в последней оф прошивке. Обновил её до не оф прошивки с 4пда. И все нормализовалось. Всем спасибо=)